# Error passing tensor/vector to a custom loss_function in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to define a custom loss function in keras which takes in additional argument as cor_weight_tensor. But since the length of the cor_weight_tensor is equal to number of data points in training set which is much larger than batch size. I am getting error. Can someone please let me know, how can I use the cor_weight_tensor of length same as batch size in each iteration. My code is given below followed by error message.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import backend

###############
##custom function to calculate loss
def custom_loss(wt):

    def loss(y_true,y_pred):
        return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))*wt
    # Return a function
    return loss
###############
###############

def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))

classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 128,init ='uniform',activation = 'relu',input_dim=19))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =128,init ='uniform',activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =64,init ='uniform',activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim =64,init ='uniform',activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(output_dim = 1 ,init ='uniform',activation = 'relu'))

classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam' , loss = custom_loss(cor_weight_tensor), metrics = [rmse])
H = classifier.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size = 64 ,epochs=10, validation_split=0.2)
```

My sample input training features (X_train) set looks like as follows (6 examples data points). Now let us say that data instance 1-2 are from one source, 3-4 are from second source, 5-6, are from third source. So I want to assign them weights based on their source. So, I have created a weight vector of length 6. The reason of creating weight vector is to give more weightage in calculating loss from samples from different source.

cor_weight_tensor = [1,1,0.75,0.75,0.66,0.66]

```
X_train

1 0.23,6.69871783,3.09982644
2 0.88,5.90097192,3.09413889
3 0.93,5.22863582,3.00215503
4 0.47,4.99313908,2.89293094
5 0.39,4.81252967,2.70707414
6 0.77,4.79805324,2.59780939
```

The sample output feature variable is

```
Y_train

0.45
0.95
0.99
0.77
0.65
0.89
```

The error message that I get make sense but how can I resolve the error.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Incompatible shapes: [64] vs. [308025]
         [[Node: loss/dense_5_loss/mul = Mul[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](metrics/rmse/Sqrt, loss/dense_5_loss/mul/y)]]
         [[Node: metrics/rmse/Mean_1/_121 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_662_metrics/rmse/Mean_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Comment: you should take the mean of the loss, I think the output dimension is wrong

Comment: The error is for cor_weight_tensor I am passing in second last line of the code in custom_loss function. The problem is that the length of the cor_weight_tensor is equal to number of data points (308025) but the batch_size is only 64 so, the custom_loss function is expecting cor_weight_tensor of length 64 in every batch. But how can I change it for every batch iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't show neither how this cor_weight_tensor is defined nor its meaning it is difficult to provide a precise answer.

Anyway, for adapting the shape of that tensor you can either compute its mean (if the tensor has the training data length then I may suppose it is some kind of statistic over the dataset) by reducing it to a single scalar or adapt it to the batch size somehow (depending on how it is defined).

In either way, if this value comes from the dataset you can see it as a new input for your model. For this reason I would suggest to use the Keras Functional API, which allow you to easily specify multiple inputs so you can adapt it to the batch size on your tensor before passing it to the loss function.

Comment: I have updated my question with sample training set and weight vector and brief explanation

Comment: In this case, since you know the sources of your input data (hence the associated weights), your dataset should output the weights as a new column of your input data (y_train can be either a list or a dictionary). 
This would be convenient because you would already have your weights embedded with the data and they get shuffled altogether, moreover your batch of weights would be always the same size of your training batch allowing element-wise multiplication.